# docker1.7 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container: invalid argument

Tags: docker, containers, docker-network

I use docker1.7 on CentOS6 (kernel: 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64).
When I run the following command:

> $ docker run --rm hello-world

I get the following errors:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container xxx: invalid argument

While the following command could run the container correctly:

> $ docker run --rm --net="none" hello-world

But when adding `--net="none"`, I couldn't map hosts between the host and the container.

Is there any tips for solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this issue 14904](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14904), it is likely because of a lack of support for some of the docker features.

Run [this script `check-config.sh`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh) to determine what is missing.